# Django, Can i call view in execution time? best method

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have a question, i explain, i have a form with two modelchoicefield and i want to fill the second modelchoice when the first is changed, both depend on from two tables joined with a foreign key relation then when i choice a value in the first modelchoice the second should load their values.

Please anyone knows the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple method would be to make selecting the first choice a post event. This would post the form at that stage back to the server, then your view code can render a new form with the second choice options based on whatever logic you need it to.

For a better UX you could run some AJAX on the page that will request the choices for the second field when the first has been selected.